# how to use 'mkString' function for this situation in Scala

Tags: scala

for example

```
scala> val test = ("TEST" * 3)
test: String = TESTTESTTEST
```

but I want to make **"TEST,TEST,TEST"**

so I tried like this. but I got a disappointing result

```
scala> val test = ("TEST" * 3).mkString(",")
test: String = T,E,S,T,T,E,S,T,T,E,S,T
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkString` is a method on the `Iterable` trait. If you apply it to a `String`, it will be implicitly converted to a `Seq[Char]`.

How about

```
scala> List.fill(3)("TEST").mkString(",")
res0: String = TEST,TEST,TEST
```

instead?

Answer (score 4):

That is because your string is than treated as a collection of chars, which are concatenated. Try

```
Array.fill(3)("TEST").mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Without the `init` there is an extra comma so `init` is used to get all elements except the last.

```
scala> (("TEST" + ",") * 3).init
res7: String = TEST,TEST,TEST
```